# Can MySQL scale for hot record use case?

Tags: mysql, scale, scalability

I am building a gaming system where users can exchange tokens in real time. Some of these users are super users who can receive millions of tokens from other users. I need persistent data store that keeps following user-token snapshot:

```
U1 300
U2 480
U3 900
U4 190000
```

If U1 sends 100 tokens to U4, following txns needs to happen as atomic

```
1. U1 debit 100
2. U4 credit 100
```

Now U4 being a superuser could have thousands of txns per second with various users. That is u4 record will be a hot record.

Can I use MySQL for persistence data store of U - token value? Will it scale? Remember I need ACID compliance since token is essentially money here so no room for error? Any suggestions?

Comment: I suspect hardware also plays a role in this. I'm tired of trying to make apps not crash on shared hosting accounts with tiny RAM and disk at 99% of its capacity.

Comment: Not a solution, but you may want to just create a table for xactions with senderid, amount, receiverid and use a single insert.  Balances are result of an aggregating query.  Credits are where I'm receiverid and debits are where I'm senderID

Comment: Thx Chris but if a debit is needed on an account, I would need to check via aggregation whether current balance is greater than amount to be debited. Doing it via aggregation on the fly for every debit would be s slow, no?